# how to make custom post with "publish" default functionality not save in draft?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

This is my custom post type code everything working fine but when i publish post, the post is being saved in draft mode.

```
     $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'supports' => $supports,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    );

    register_post_type(self::$PostTypeName, $args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'wp_insert_post_data' filter hook for that kind of problem

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_post_data', 99, 2);

function filter_post_data($postData, $postarr) {

    if ($postData['post_status'] == 'draft') {
        $postData['post_status'] = 'publish';
    }

    return $postData;
}
```